# Jmeter - how to implement another java class

Tags: java, itext, jmeter

Greetings all,

In another post I asked about rendering PDF in Jmeter, and it would seem the solution is to use iText.

Using iText requires installing another library and referencing it. Does anyone know how to do this? I can't find a tutorial. Much thanks. iText is also dependent upon bouncycastle

iText: http://www.1t3xt.com/downloads/index.php
iText dependency: http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add it to your classpath when running JMeter.  Unfortunately in the jmeter.bat or jmeter.sh they run JMeter using the -jar flag which will ignore your custom classpath.  To get around this you need to simply include the ApacheJMeter jar in your class path and run the class org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver as your starting class.